# Novel with giant wasps from outer space

Tags: story-identification, novel

I recall reading a sci-fi/horror novel from the 80's or maybe early 90's where Earth was overrun by giant wasps from outer space.  There was a section in the beginning with airliners being abducted by an alien force, though I don't recall how it tied in.

Can anyone ID this one?

Comment: This is very broad, can you add _any_ more details? You might want to check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if it helps jog your memory.

Comment: Is it possible it is The Furies by Keith Roberts? Never actually got round to reading myself but always remember the cover from my local library in in the late 80's.

Comment: here is the cover if it helps... https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1332885615l/2332214.jpg

Comment: Found this on the encyclopaedia of SF website. "The Furies is a traditional tale in the mode of the UK Disaster, in which a nuclear test goes awry, inspiring an onslaught of space-spawned giant wasps which ravage England and come close to eliminating mankind". It seems to fit, if this is the book I'll mark this up as the answer.

Comment: @dominicfonde Just in case the OP didn't read the same edition you did, here are all the covers: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?22674

Comment: So, so tempted to suggest it was War of the Wasps by Garth Marenghi... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EuKXFr2pr-A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be Keith Roberts *The Furies*. That certainly involved giant wasps.

It's a long time since I read it, but I recall that the ending was a bit feeble.

> "The Insects are dying. Racial senescence."

whatever that means.